# Why did my reputation first increase and then decrease in answering a question

Tags: discussion, support

I gave the answer to a question, and the owner of the question was satisfied with the answer. First he marked it as accepted, and then he marked another one. Why is it so?

The question is *[array1.splice(1,1) is removing data from array2 which I have created using array1.slice(0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37208095/array1-splice1-1-is-removing-data-from-array2-which-i-have-created-using-array/37208416#37208416)*.

You can see the comment of owner or question.

Comment: Sometimes it happens, more than 1 answer is helpful to a person. Maybe the accepted answer helped OP more?

Comment: if u open the link then note that question owner thanks wording comment . other answer is not usefull . note the comment on that answer :(

Comment: The check mark is for the OP to use however they want.  Sorry but that is the way it is.

Comment: Please do not tell users to accept your answer. You wrote in comments on your answer "u welcome accept my answer" and "if it help u then u mark it write i need reputation". At best, these are non-constructive comments and worthy of deletion. At worst, they constitute badgering the OP. If a user seems to not know how accepting answers work, it is okay to explain the principle, but that's as far is it should go.

Comment: @Louis i need reputation so im trying hard . my answer help her out . well ok i understand

Comment: @Asad you should get reputation because your answers are good, not because you are begging for it. Remember that you will get more rep from upvotes in the history of your good answer than the accepted checkmark can ever give you. Just mkae sure your answers are pristine, and they will get the score they deserve.

Comment: The old dating rule applies: "don't appear needy"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have answered the question yourself. The OP first accepted your answer, giving you +15 reputation. Later when the acceptance was revoked, those 15 points were deducted too. Hence, your reputation first increased and then decreased.

Also, I see you received no votes (up/down) on the answer. Hence your effective reputation remained constant.

As far as why the OP did that, that's a matter of choice. The other answer seemed to be more helpful to her. Don't be disheartened, keep up the spirit and contribute. High reputation is just a state of mind!

Comment: if u open the link then note that question owner thanks wording comment . other answer is not usefull . note the comment on that answer :(

Comment: i want to gain reputation but dnt know y people do so . my answer help her . u can check her comment @CinCout

Comment: Dude, I read the comment. But nothing can be done here. One who asks the question is the most suited to decide which answer was the most helpful.

Comment: @Asad It's still the OP choice to accept an answer.. Just keep going on. There are enough other questions to gain reputation.

Comment: i post here cause i faced it 3rd time ..

Comment: well okay :) thanks for your time